# socketserver listening on multiple ports

Tags: python, tcp, socketserver

I am trying to write a TCP server in Python 3.6.7 using [`socketserver`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#module-socketserver), that listens on two ports on the same IP address. This is what I came up with up to now:

```py
import socketserver

class TCPServer(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
        print(str(self.data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST = "localhost"
    DATA_PORT = 64000
    CONTROL_PORT = 64001
    data_server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, DATA_PORT), TCPServer)
    control_server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, CONTROL_PORT), TCPServer)

    try:
        while True:
            data_server.handle_request()
            control_server.handle_request()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        data_server.server_close()
        control_server.server_close()
```

Then I try to speak with the server using the following client:

```py
import socket
from time import sleep

HOST = "localhost"
DATA_PORT = 64000
CONTROL_PORT = 64001
data = "test data"

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock_d, socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM
) as sock_c:
    sock_d.connect((HOST, DATA_PORT))
    sock_c.connect((HOST, CONTROL_PORT))
    for cnt in range(5):
        sock_d.sendall(bytes(data + " " + str(cnt) + "\n", "utf-8"))
        print("Sent:     {}".format(cnt))
        sock_c.sendall(bytes(data + " " + str(cnt + 1) + "\n", "utf-8"))
        print("Sent:     {}".format(cnt + 1))
        sleep(1)
```

What happens is that on the client side I get this output:

```
Sent:     0
Sent:     1
Sent:     1
Sent:     2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<...> client_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    sock_d.sendall(bytes(data + " " + str(cnt) + "\n", "utf-8"))
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

while on the server I only get:

```
b'test data 0'
b'test data 1'
```

Can someone help me and point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: I think that `handle_request` gets new connected client, runs `handle()` which reads single line of data from socket (and ends its job) and after that it disconnects client to wait for connection from another client. So you would have to use loop inside `handler()` to read more lines from client.

Comment: but from the [`handle_request` source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/socketserver.py#L273) I can't see where it would disconnect...

Comment: in source you can see: when request is `ready` (`select.select()`) then it executes `_handle_request_noblock()` which `get_request()` and later it runs `shutdown_request()`

Comment: sorry I still don't see it: `shutdown_request == close_request == pass`... so it does nothing.

Comment: you checked code for `BaseServer` - see for `TCPServer` - there is `request.close()` instead of `pass` - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/socketserver.py#L511

Comment: oh silly me! I'll go through it more carefully and report back, thanks for your patience @furas

Comment: still waiting on that report @charlie80

Comment: sorry @nurettin, project was abandoned so I cannot give you a feedback...